# Unable to create JMS Receiver in WSO2 CEP

Tags: wso2, jms, wso2-cep

I am using WSO2 CEP v4.1.0. I have already created 1 JMS receiver and it works fine, And then I try to add another JMS receiver, Then one of error message alert was given by CEP, but no any carbon console messages were printed in console. Is this a bug of WSO2 CEP?

Error message screen cap is given below

[image]

Steps to reproduce the problem -

1.Create new JMS receiver with the following details (Above image with error message shows the filled data.)

- Input Event Adapter Type -JMS
- Topic/Queue Name - param3
- JNDI Initial Context Factory Class -
  org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory
- Connection Factory JNDI Name- TopicConnectionFactory
- JMS connection username - admin
- JMS connection password - admin
- JNDI Provider URL - repository/conf/jndi.properties
- Destination Type - topic

2.Create another receiver with same details with different topic name

- Topic/Queue Name - param4

3.jndi property that is used for both is

> ```
> # register some connection factories
> # connectionfactory.[jndiname] = [ConnectionURL]
> connectionfactory.TopicConnectionFactory=amqp://admin:admin@clientid/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5672'
>
> # register some queues in JNDI using the form
> # queue.[jndiName] = [physicalName]
>
> # register some topics in JNDI using the form
> # topic.[jndiName] = [physicalName]
> topic.param1 = param1
> topic.param2 = param2
> topic.param3 = param3
> topic.param4 = param4
> ```

4.Advanced property mapping has been done by according to the properties.

Comment: Would it be possible to list out the steps to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @Dilini I have edited question with the steps that i followed.

Comment: @SaveendraEkanayake , I have followed your replication steps and I was able to successfully create two receivers as you have requested without any errors. Is there a backend exception in your server logs other than the error message in UI?

Comment: @Pubudu No any error logs. I found the reason when adding property mapping with map, It will provide that error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saveendra,

It is not an issue with JMS receiver or no of jms receivers.. It is an issue with MAP custom mapping where it does not allow to save a custom mapping without a default value.. It is an UI issue..

I have fixed that issue now in [this](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-analytics-common/commit/ad4df4502b287b62ca4c7f9b4ba06445fce4941c) commit (and fix will be there in next release).. For the moment, add an appropriate default value for the custom mapping and continue (or deploy the event receiver through file system or use the edit UI)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug, It will happen when adding property mapping with map type, It will provide the above error message. Therefore without filling advanced details which is related to mapping, create new receiver and then edit the receiver XML and add that mapping manually. It will be saving successfully.